# Remapping a pandas dataframe column using a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm quite new to python so bear with me if this is obvious.

I've got a column, 'age', in a dataframe, dff, containing the values 1 to 66. Each value corresponds to a key in the dictionary, di, and I'm trying to replace the values in the column with the corresponding values from the dictionary.

I can do this for a single value, for example:

```
dff['age'] = dff['age'].replace('1', di.get('1'))
```

But I want to do it for all 66 values. I tried this:

```
i = 1
while i <= 66:
    i = str(i)
    dff['age'] = dff['age'].replace(i, di.get(i))
    i = int(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Which doesn't seem to change the values in the column at all. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: sorry are you wanting `dff['age'] = dff['age'].map(di)`? also your issue with the `for` loop is you're overwriting the entire column on each iteration so the last iteration will persist

Comment: Thank for the quick response, @EdChum. I've tried map, but that only ever seems to return NaN for every value.

Comment: If "each value corresponds to a key in the dictionary, di" then it should work well. Check the types of the keys if it's returning NaN.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @ayhan . My keys are str and the values int. How do I sort this?

Comment: You can temporarily change the age column `dff[age].astype(str).map(di)` or it would be better to modify the dictionary: `di = {int(k): v for k, v in di.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

I think `.replace()` will do a better job. `.map()` fills `nans` if a particular match is not found. Purely depends on which is the desired output

```
dff['age'] = dff['age'].replace(di)
```

For example

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], columns=['age'])

df['age'].replace({'a': '10-25', 'b': '50-60'})
0    10-25
1    50-60
2        c
3        d
4    10-25
Name: age, dtype: object
```

Where `.map()` will introduce `nan`.

```
dff['age'].map({'a': '10-25', 'b': '50-60'})
0    10-25
1    50-60
2      NaN
3      NaN
4    10-25
Name: age, dtype: object
```